# Statistics for Disabled Veterans in Residential Homes

Tags: usa, data.gov, real-estate

I am looking for the data/statistics for the disabled veteran population in California that are currently living in adult residential care homes.

Comment: You could try making a request here: https://www.data.gov/data-request/

Comment: You can also try contacting Cal Vets as well: https://www.calvet.ca.gov/